# Generate k random list from a list of elements possibly containing sublist

Tags: python, random

I have a list `l` in the following form. I need to randomly generate `k` (six in this example) number of lists from this list so that only one element is selected from the sublists at a time.

```
l = [1,2,3,[11,22,33,44], 4,5,6, [22,33,44], 5, [99,88]]

Result: 

1,2,3, 22, 4,5,6, 22 ,5, 88
1,2,3, 33, 4,5,6, 44 ,5, 88
1,2,3, 44, 4,5,6, 22 ,5, 99
1,2,3, 22, 4,5,6, 33 ,5, 99
1,2,3, 33, 4,5,6, 33 ,5, 99
1,2,3, 33, 4,5,6, 44 ,5, 88
```

I can write a for loop and pick a random element whenever I encountered a list. But i am looking for more elegant pythonic way to do this.

```
l = [1,2,3,[11,22,33,44], 4,5,6, [22,33,44], 5, [99,88]]
k = 0
for k in range(6):
    new_l = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if isinstance(l[i], list):
            new_l.append(np.random.choice(l[i]))
        else:
            new_l.append(l[i])
    print(new_l)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Yes, have you tried anything? Looked at the `random` module? Iterate over your list, check if the element is a list, if so, choose a random element, else, keep the non-list (i.e. the int...) What exactly is tripping you up? Checking `if` something is a list? Choosing a random element from a list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, edited my OP.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, wrote  the code to answer your request.

Comment: What? So how does this not work? What is the question? And why are you using `numpy`?

Comment: he's asking for a more pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: @JahKnows the only thing not pythonic about the OP's code is that it is iterating over the index instead of directly over the list, so something like `[random.choice(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in l]` would be better (as a list-comprehension or a for-loop, it doesn't matter). However, if the code is working, this is better suited for  [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key function to use is `choice` from the `random` module, which randomly selects a value from any iterable object with a known size. All such objects have a `__getitem__` method as well as a `__len__` method (both of which are needed to apply the `choice` function), so the builtin function `hasattr` can be used to check whether `choice` can be applied or not. The solution becomes straightforward:

```
from random import choice

l = [1,2,3,[11,22,33,44], 4,5,6, [22,33,44], 5, [99,88]]

for n in range(6):
    print([choice(item) if hasattr(item,'__getitem__') else item for item in l])
```

Comment: "All iterable objects have a `__len__`" Not true. Many iterable things do not have a `__len__`. This is rather strange approach, although it works, it is better to explicitly check `isinstance(x, list)`

Comment: @juanpa: it's not a strange approach at all, it's called **"duck typing"** and its the prefered way to deal with such things in Python. Using `isinstance` is much less pythonic and much more restricted. All iterable objects have a `__len__` method, though testing `__getitem__` is bettter here (so I edited the code).

Comment: Um, again, that is simply not true. Not all iterable objects have a `__len__` method or a `__getitem__` method. If you really wanted to check for an object being iterable, you would use `hasattr('__iter__')`.

Comment: @juanpa: strings are iterable but don't have a `__iter__` attribute, so your test fails. Testing `__getitem__` is much safer, because almost any iterable data structure implements the [...] accessor. Of course you may always generate a pathological case where you implement `__iter__` and not `__getitem__` but that's very uncommon in practice. Anyway, using `hasattr` is much less restrictive as the `isinstance` solution you proposed in your first comment.

Comment: `str` objects have an `__iter__` method. But `map`, `filter`, and generator objects all do not have a `__getitem__` nor a `__len__`. Those are not uncommnon or pathalogical at all.

Comment: @juanpa: no `__iter__` for strings in Python 2.x. If you are so convinced that `isinstance` is a better solution, I would really be pleased to hear about a solution based on `isinstance` that works for all iterable structures ?

Comment: @juanpa: To close this rather unpleasant discussion, I suggest you to have a look at the source code for function `choice` in module `random`. The only methods it uses are `__len__` and `__getitem__`, so testing the presence of these attributes is clearly the right answer in a duck typing approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat this procedure 6 times. It randomly reorders your inner lists and takes the first value.

```
l = [1,2,3,[11,22,33,44], 4,5,6, [22,33,44], 5, [99,88]]

for i in range(6):
    print([np.random.permutation(i)[0] if type(i) == list 
           else np.random.permutation([i])[0] 
           for i in l])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too:

```
import random

l = [1,2,3,[11,22,33,44], 4,5,6, [22,33,44], 5, [99,88]]

res = [random.choice(l[i]) if type(l[i]) is list else l[i] for i in range(len(l))]

print(res)
```

Possible outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 44, 4, 5, 6, 22, 5, 99]
[1, 2, 3, 11, 4, 5, 6, 22, 5, 99]
[1, 2, 3, 22, 4, 5, 6, 33, 5, 88]
```